# Format Rows in endless form in Access2007

Tags: formatting, ms-access-2007, continuous-forms

I have an continous form in my database application. In this form the data of a table with 3 columns is showed: product, numberofItemsOfToday, numberOfItemsOfYesterday.

Now I want the rows to be colored in red (ForeColor), if numberofItemsOfToday != numberOfItemsOfYesterday in the correspondent row.

I tried something like

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
    addConditionalFormatingText txtnumberofItemsOfToday, numberOfItemsOfYesterday, txtProduct, txtnumberofItemsOfToday, txtnumberOfItemsOfYesterday
End Sub

Private Sub addConditionalFormatingText(field1 As Object, field2 As Object, t1 As TextBox, t2 As TextBox, t3 As TextBox)
    Dim color As Long
    color = IIf(CBool(Nz(field1.Value, "") <> Nz(field2.Value, "")), RGB(255, 0, 0), RGB(0, 0, 0))
    t1.ForeColor = color
    t2.ForeColor = color
    t3.ForeColor = color
End Sub
```

But of course the problem is that if in one row the values are different, all rows are colored red. How can I only set the color of a special row in a continous form?

Comment: Why not use *real* conditional formatting http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/change-the-appearance-of-a-control-by-using-conditional-formatting-HA010208133.aspx ?

Comment: You appear to be re-inventing the wheel, using Remou's link should help you achieve what you need in < 5 minutes with no coding effort.

Comment: Thank you very much! I didnt know that function. That is exactly what I was looking for.